# Bridge distribution

Tags: bridge

I set up a bridge with obfs4 and successfully tested it with the Tor Browser. It has been running for over a month now and still has no users. The normal relay I set up parallel on another server is doing fine so far with a consensus weight of 568.
Now I wonder whether I did something wrong and whether my bridge is actually going to be used some time.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Me and some more users here have the same “problem”. Seems to be normal. Maybe the need for bridges isnt that big and there are more bridges then people who need them.
But i am also not completely sure about that...

Comment: These days censors discover bridges faster than normal users...

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured that the `PublishServerDescriptor` setting in  `torrc` has been set to `PublishServerDescriptor bridge`.

By setting it to `bridge` your relay will publish its descriptor
to the bridge authorities making your bridge visible to other users.

Vice versa, if you set `PublishServerDescriptor` to `0` your relay will not publish anywhere. In other words your bridge will be private.

Please refer to [bridges-spec.txt](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/attic/bridges-spec.txt) to find out more about the configuration of bridges.

Comment: This isn't required, if you configure it as a bridge it will default to bridge publication.

Comment: `PublishServerDescriptor` is commented with `#` in my torrc, so by its description and as noted in above comment it should default to advertising the bridge. I'll try to set it to `bridge`.